# sign in problem asp.net core 3 react identity server at /authentication/login-callback

Tags: reactjs, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.0, oidc-client-js

I just started a project using dot net core 3 react with individual user account template.
also made a self sign certificate *.pfx file and uploaded to server.

the problem is when I try to signing in after www.example.com/authentication/login-callback?code=** I get this error: "There was an error signing in."
in terminal:

> POST https://www.example.com/connect/token 400 
>     There was an error signing in:  Error:  (400)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.a.onload (oidc-client.min.js:737)

but when I paste this URL in browser: www.example/Identity/Account/Manage I see that I'm logged in and every thing is OK.
but AuthorizeService cant make jwt token and log me in.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. This is the expected behavior.

**https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2484**

In the case of AFT(AntiForgeryToken) usage with SPA, the XSRF token generated by the server is for unauthenticated/anonymous user, as soon as the user logs in, the user will not be logged in again. we ran into a similar problem during our implementation and this happens only when the user has login screen opened in multiple tabs. In all other use cases, the SPA(Identity servers clients) needs to validate JWT in local/session storage and if it is not valid should send the user to identity servers login page.

**There are ways you can fix this error, but that is not straight forward and it is a hack**, you need to have an exception handler middleware which looks for 400 error code and then checks for HTTP context and if the user is valid and logged in, send the user to respective clients return URL.

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2676#issuecomment-439893334